# How to renice a PID dynamically?

Tags: bash

On our development server, we have a bunch of shell script wrappers for Java JARs. Using the CRON scheduler, we do fire these scripts daily for different purposes.

For performance testing, we would like to renice a script's PID to a priority of 1 at runtime.

Right now, we do it from the command line or using TOP.

Is there a way to do that within the shell script itself without "doing harm" to the process as well as other processes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
renice -n 1 $$
```

Afterwards the script itself will have a nice value of 1. This will also apply to all new children, although not to previously forked ones.

Comment: My man page for `renice` shows nothing on the "$$". Can you please explain the significance?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify that part: $$ is expanded by bash to the PID of the running script. More information here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID

Comment: I get a `renice: 1: setpriority: Operation not permitted 13711: old priority 0, new priority 0`. Do I have to be `root`? I should not have to, correct?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need special privileges when renicing a process of your own to priorities higher than 0 *and* the current priority. If it's failing with 1 perhaps the current priority is lower (absolute number is higher)?

Comment: You can print the current priority by calling `nice` with no parameters.

Comment: On my machine (Slackware) you need `renice 1 $$`, there's no `-n` parameter

Comment: @Michal: right on. I am running RedHat. Using `renice 1 $$` worked!!